# Can I use audit logs to determine if an end user device has a synced copy of a library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, auditing

We are actively looking at o365 in our organization. One of the barriers for entry is we want to use Document Libraries to serve content to end users. These documents are required to be up to date on end user devices. If they are not and an audit happens bad things could happen to the company.

In a trial environment we have Auditing turned on and I am seeing logs. However I can only see things like *Accessed File*, *Download File* etc. Understandably there does not appear to be an entry like "Synced Library".

End users will only have one device so I should not have to worry about library state on multiple end points.

Can I use the data from the Audit Logs to accurately determine the sync status of a library on an end user device i.e. is the device out of date?

Some of these documents will not change for years so I could never see activity for a given file meaning 90 days worth of activity might make this hard to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.The audit log captures the following information for the events that are selected to be audited.

- Site from which an event originated
- Item ID, type, name, and location
- User ID associated with the event
- Event type, date, time, and source
- Action taken on the item

More information is in this article:
[Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2)

Comment: I suppose I could capture all the information into another location and compare the current timestamps of every file against the history to ensure that each file was downloaded but that seems like inviting margins of error.